# How to write a function with a 2-dimensional array as its argument?

Tags: c#, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I am a novice in C#.

I have a 2-dimensional array called "board":

```
short[,] board = new short[8,8];
```

And I am using a function called "color" which returns "White" if a White chess piece is on the square [i,j], "Black" if a Black chess piece is on the square [i,j], and "None" if the square [i,j] is empty.

```
if(color[board[i,j]]==White)
{
    do something
}

static string color(short[,,,,] t)
        {
            string Color;

            if(t[m,n]==X)
            {
                Color=None;
            }

            if(t[m,n]==WP || t[m,n]==WN || t[m,n]==WB || t[m,n]==WR || t[m,n]==WQ || t[m,n]==WK)
            {
                Color=White;
            }

            if(t[m,n]==BP || t[m,n]==BN || t[m,n]==BB || t[m,n]==BR || t[m,n]==BQ || t[m,n]==BK)
            {
                Color=Black;
            } 

            return Color;
        }
```

X, WP, BP, WN, BN, etc..., are just things that I declared earlier and that represent the chess pieces: X=Nothing, WP=White Pawn, BP=Black Pawn, WN=White kNight, BN=Black kNight, etc...

But I don't know how to write the color function. Where do I declare the variables `m` and `n`? I want them to correspond to the variables i and j respectively.

And I am not even sure how to call the function in the Main. Do I write `color[board[i,j]]` or `color[board, i, j]` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify this problem you need to change the signature of the color method. I would make it

```
public static string Color(short piece)
{
    string color = String.Empty;

    //Because we are passing in the short array value we don't 
    //need to get it from the array we can just use it eg:
    if(piece == WP)
        color = "White";

    //Your other if statements go here
    return color;
 }
```

Then to call the method you would use

```
if (Color(board[i][j]) == "White")
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Just some extra things I want to note, the C# naming convention for Methods is it starts with a Capital letter and your code might be better if you use an ENUM to represent the pieces rather than short constants.

EDIT:

If you were to use an ENUM it would look something like this

```
enum Pieces { WP, WN, WB /* etc... */ }
```

This is a better solution because each piece doesn't have an explicit value associated with it, it's all done automatically. Additionally it's a lot neater because you don't have ten's of lines at the start of your class explaining all the pieces, this is shorter and more concise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But could you elaborate on "use an ENUM to represent the pieces"? (I must admit that before beginning to write my program I hesitated between using strings or using shorts for the chess pieces) Do you mean like this? : enum Pieces : int {X, WP, WN, WB, WR, WQ, WK, BP, BN, BB, BR, BQ, BK}; Why would it be better to use an ENUM rather than short constants?

Comment: You're welcome, I've edited my post to explain what I mean about enums.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
static string color(short[,] t, int m, int n)
{
    var colors = new Dictionary<string, short[]>()
    {
        { None, new [] { X } },
        { White, new [] { WP, WN, WB, WR, WQ, WK } },
        { Black, new [] { BP, BN, BB, BR, BQ, BK } },
    };

    return
        colors
            .Where(x => x.Value.Contains(t[m, n]))
            .Select(x => x.Key)
            .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

NB: I assume that `None`, `White`, & `Black` are variables otherwise they'd need to be in double-quotes if you meant them as string literals.